# Use optparse to call a function

Tags: python, linux, argparse, python-2.6, optparse

**How to call a function using optparse**? I do not want to use argparse.
Here is my code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
def print_stuff():
   a = "Hello Word"

   print a
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c",
              action = "callback",
              callback = print_stuff()
              )
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

But it shows me an error:

```
optparse.OptionError: option -c: callback not callable: None
```

What to do?

What if I wanted to do:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
def print_stuff(a):
   a = "Hello Word"

   return a
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c",
              action = "callback",
              callback = print_stuff()
              )
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: remove parentheses: `callback = print_stuff` or you're calling the function

Comment: Did and does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
callback = print_stuff
```

without the parens. Including the parens invokes the function, and sets callback to the result (the string "Hello Word"), which is not callable. Without the parens, you're referring to the function itself.

Comment: Does not work show the following error

`self.callback(self, opt, value, parser, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: print_stuff() takes no arguments (4 given)`


Code:

`from optparse import OptionParser
def print_stuff():
    a = "there"
    print a
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c",
                  action = "callback",
                  callback = print_stuff
                  )
args = ["-c"]
(options, args) = parser.parse_args(args)

`

Comment: That means that it did work – it's now attempting to call the function. You now have a different kind of problem, which is that your callback doesn't take enough arguments. The optparse docs mention that all callbacks must take at least 4, and describes them: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks